# SQL: how to use two conditions whith dependences?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have database where is unique customer ID.

I what to know what products they have bought before specified product. I have a list when specified ID has bought bananas I want to search all products and dates before that.

Example I have data:

```
CustomerID Product Date
123        banana  2015-03-15
111        banana  2014-07-09
321        banana  2013-04-03
```

How I can write SQL command search all products what Customer have bought before that date?
Example

```
CustomerID Product Date
123        Apple   2014-05-07
123        Kiwi    2014-05-06
123        Pen     2012-12-12
111        Pen     2014-07-07
111        Milk    2010-01-30
321        Milk    2012-02-12
```

Comment: have you any specific date?, Pls mention it

Comment: @HardeepSingh I understand that there is no specific date, because the date will depend on when a given customer bought product **X**, and will be different for each customer.

Comment: then you have to mention customer ID

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you. The table name is contrived, so you will need to replace it.

```
SELECT CustomerID, Product, Date
FROM ProductTable p1
WHERE Date < (
    SELECT MAX(Date) 
    FROM ProductTable p2 
    WHERE p2.CustomerID = p1.CustomerID AND p2.Product = 'banana'
)  
ORDER BY CustomerID, Date;
```

Answer (score 2):

@Peter Abolins's answer is correct, but does not handle the case when the customer has never bought a banana yet.

To handle this case, the request would become:

```
SELECT CustomerID, Product, Date
FROM ProductTable p1
WHERE Date < (
    SELECT IFNULL (
        (SELECT MAX(Date) 
        FROM ProductTable p2 
        WHERE p2.CustomerID = p1.CustomerID AND p2.Product = 'banana'),
        '9999-12-31'
        )
)  
ORDER BY CustomerID, Date;
```

PS: I know that this should be a comment, but I cannot comment with this account yet.

Comment: If a customer has never bought a banana, then logically, they never bought anything before it. It all depends on what the OP wanted. Your solution assumes that they will buy a banana in the future, and therefore everything they have bought so far will be listed.

Comment: From a robustness point of view, I agree with your solution, but the date could just as well be set to '1970-01-01' if they have never bought a banana. And this would be (in my mind) more correct.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, setting the date to '1970-01-01' makes also sense. All depends on the OP's needs. In my mind, getting all the products if a banana was never bought made more sense, because I see the banana purchase as a "limit closing the list". But I understand your logic too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but give it a try and look at the results:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA AS a 
         JOIN tableA AS b 
         ON a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID AND a.Date > b.Date 
ORDER BY a.CustomerID, a.Product, a.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two tables, the first table with a list of customer ID, and dates for a specified product, and the second table with the history of product sold to that customer.

We will call them respectively `LIST` and `HIST`, you can get your desired output with:

```
SELECT p1.CustomerID, p2.Product, p2.Date
FROM LIST p1
left join HIST p2 on p2.CustomerID = p1.CustomerID AND P1.Date > P2.Date 
ORDER BY p1.CustomerID, p2.Date;
```